# Variables resetting when transitioning to another ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to show an alert view in my app when the user is at a specific location. Also, I only want to present this alert view once. For this,
I have the following code:

```
if(!hasShownAlertview && GMSGeometryContainsLocation(userLocation.coordinate, testPath, YES)){
            hasShownAlertview = YES;

            UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title" message@"Body" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

            UIAlertAction *yesAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"YES", nil) style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:
                                             ^(UIAlertAction *action){
                                            }];

            UIAlertAction *noAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"NO", nil) style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:
                                        ^(UIAlertAction *action){
                                        }];

            [alertController addAction:noAction];
            [alertController addAction:yesAction];
            [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

**The problem is:** If I go to another ViewController, while the user is still at that location, the alert view is shown again on that ViewController. Reason behind this, is that `hasShownAlertview` is set back to NO just before the new ViewController is presented, so the alert view is being shown again.

How could I solve this issue?

Comment: how you declare `hasShownAlertview` can you show?

Comment: It is declared in the .h file as an ivar

Comment: Make property `Strong` of `hasShownAlertview`

Comment: Yes but you can-t do that with a BOOL, you can only retain objects!

Answer (score 0):

You can declare `hasShownAlertview` in `appdelegate` and can use it anywhere in app to check that whether it is yes or no. And you should take strong reference of that property so it is not dealloc.

Comment: Thanks, but it's a Bool, can not have strong reference to bools

Comment: Then try to take it in `appdelegate`, If you want to take `strong` reference then you can take `NSString` instead bool and set `yes or no` and compare it with `isequaltostring` or you can take `NSInteger`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by declaring `hasShownAlertview` as `static` in the `.m` file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use static `hasShownAlertView` variable in multiple files, you should do like this.

in `Appelegate.h`, delcare

```
@property (assign) bool hasShownAlertView;
```

At any file you want to check or change the value, you get `hasShownAlertView` variable by

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
bool hasShownAlertView = appDelegate.hasShownAlertView;
```